# What is a fantastic image processing library for java that does levels, colour balance, saturation, sharpness, noise reduction and compression?

Tags: java, api, image, image-processing

What is a fantastic image processing library for java that does levels, colour balance, saturation, sharpness, noise reduction and compression? I'm looking for something that is easy to learn, and has a high-level API... not something low level, unless it's the only option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it satisfies all your requirements, but [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org) is a good image processing library for Java - it's an interface to the well-known ImageMagick image processing tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think JAI provides pretty good coverage of features, but it might not fall into easy-to-use category.

Answer (score 0):

try http://jhlabs.com jerry has a very extensive filtering library available for download.